# Faster method of copying bounding box content onto canvas with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, profiling

I have an image with several detections with bounding boxes that overlap. I want to be able to extract different combinations of overlapping boxes onto a blank canvas, then save it as an image.

To visualise, if there are detections like this:

[image: Example overlapping boxes]

I want to be able to test boxes 1+2, 1+3, 2+3 with the box not included set to white.
To do this I'm using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

#orig = cv2.imread("Orig.jpg")
orig = np.zeros((9536, 13480, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # dummy
print(orig.shape)
rects = [[1000,1000,1100,1100], [1100,1000,1200,1100],[1100,1100,1200,1200]]
loops = 10


starttime = time.perf_counter()
blankCanvas = np.full(orig.shape, (255,255,255), np.uint8)

for i in range(loops):
    canvas = blankCanvas.copy()
    for rect in rects:
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = rect
        canvas[y1:y2,x1:x2] = orig[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    xs = np.hstack((np.array(rects)[:,0],np.array(rects)[:,2]))
    ys = np.hstack((np.array(rects)[:,1],np.array(rects)[:,3]))
    cv2.imwrite(str(i) + ".jpg", canvas[min(ys):max(ys), min(xs):max(xs)])
fulltime = time.perf_counter()-starttime

looptime = fulltime/loops
recttime = looptime/len(rects)
print("Time taken per loop:: ", looptime)
print("Time taken per rect:: ", recttime)
```

---

```
Output:::
(9536, 13480, 3)
Time taken per loop::  0.22753073000000001
Time taken per rect::  0.07584357666666668
```

Each loop is taking roughly quarter a second, the issue is I have to do thousands of loops. I managed to speed it up by copying a blank canvas rather than reinitizializing the canvas every loop, but I'm not sure how else I can optimise the process of copying across sections to the canvas.

The majority of time in a loop is spend on this section:

```
canvas = blankCanvas.copy()
for rect in rects:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = rect
    canvas[y1:y2,x1:x2] = orig[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Writing to disk doesn't seem to make any difference to timing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Test your code without the imwrite in the loop. I would be surprised if writing to disk + compressing to jpg is not taking the biggest chunk of processing time in there. If this is indeed the case, are there ways to go about this other to save each in a single file ? A multipage TIFF maybe ? Just a CSV with the coordinates found ? What happens next with your data ?

Comment: good catch, @nick! the imwrite will definitely dominate that loop. OP, why didn't you time your code without it yet? you should have examined the parts of that entire loop for individual timing.

Comment: Testing with and without cv2.imwrite shows no difference in timings unfortunately.

Comment: ok then, thorough profiling please. timings on every line, loop block, and loop. python comes with a profiler. standalone, it's not as user-friendly as some commercial tools but it's bearable. I'm sure some IDEs integrate it in their UI. -- why is there constant setup code included in the timing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop time is dominated by the `np.full` (~500 ms) and the `.copy()` (100 ms).

The actual calculations cost *four orders of magnitude* less time.

You introduced the `.copy()` operation purely for the time measurement, so your measurement method disturbed the thing you tried to measure.

You also included constant setup cost (the `np.full`) when you only tried to determine the cost of the actual calculation.

Please use a profiler: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: That is a seriously helpful link, thank you for that !

Comment: I introduced the copy as it was an optimisation, I intended to measure function time with it in. That profiling link is brilliant, appreciate that. Looks like i just need to try find an optimisation specifically for the .copy() operation, thanks!!